# Calling function from dll in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call a few functions in a .dll file from my python program but my python program can't find the functions at all. I've used a few different ctypes methods but haven't gotten anywhere.

I've tried:

```
self.dll = ctypes.WinDLL('C:\Windows\System32\DLLNAME')

self.dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\Windows\System32\DLLNAME')

self.dll = CDLL('C:\Windows\System32\DLLNAME')
```

where DLLNAME is the name of my dll. I have double and triple checked that the dll is in the win\sys32 library and has the same name.

I'm then going down to the next line and saying

```
self.dll.USB_PM()
```

where USB_PM() is the name of the first function I need to access. This throws the error

```
AttributeError: function 'USB_PM' not found
```

This is taking place in a class, hence the self. included there.

---

PC: Windows 10

Python: 3.9, 32 bit

DLL: MiniCircuits activex DLL, registered with RegSvr32

DLL can be found [here](https://www.minicircuits.com/softwaredownload/pm.html)

Comment: double your backslashes `"c:\\windows\\system32\\<name>"` or use `r"c:\windows\system32\<name>` ([raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) python 3). Otherwise you're just escaping the character following the backslash.

Comment: @Neitsa I tried both, still can't find the function

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit interpreter? If you're using a 32-bit one, it won't be able to see `\system32`, but will search in `\syswow64`.

Comment: Everything is set to the 32 bit versions

Comment: Could you add to the question what your system is (32-bit vs 64-) what your python interpreter is, and for which system your DLL is for?

Comment: @Neitsa added, thanks

Answer (score 0):

32-but apps cannot read or write c:\windows\system32 on 64-bit to prevent using or corrupting the 64-bit DLLs there. 32-bit apps are redirected to c:\windows\syswow64 instead. Place your 32-bit DLL there and simply use:

```
dll = WinDLL('dllname')
```

Path isn’t required as that directory is a standard search path for DLLs.